# How I can get array which values were get in method of another class

Tags: java, android, arrays, charts, timertask

*In mainActivity I made timer,which you click in button each 3 seconds show value of available memory and write in array.And after writting finished, the second button "see chart" stay clickable,we click and transwer to the next activity(second class).
 In second class creates canvas with lines, and must be create chart which can show available memory in time.* **But I can't carry array in first class to second class.**

**I need carry array "Masiv " at method run() to my second class.**

**First class**

```
package foxstrot.p3;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Timer timer;
    private MyTimerTask myTimerTask;
    private Intent i;
    long[] Masiv =  new long[50];
    int k;


    private long freeMemory;

    private Canvas canvas;
    private G.DrawView d;

    private int t = 0;
    private long j;
    private TextView tv;
    private long r;
    private Button b2;
    MyTimerTask myTimerTask1 = new MyTimerTask();
    int ii = 0;
    ArrayList <Integer> AL  = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);


        b2.setClickable(false);
        //myTimerTask1.getMas();


        //actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
        //freeMemory = memInfo.availMem;
        //tv.setText("freeMemory: " + freeMemory);
        //Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        /*G g = new G();
        G.DrawView d = g.new DrawView(this);*/






    }
    public void start(View v) {

        timer = new Timer();
        myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 3000, 3000);



    }

    public void chart(View v){
        i = new Intent(this,G.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }







    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {




    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    long getFreeMemory(){
        ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
        freeMemory = memInfo.availMem;
        return freeMemory;
    }


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {



                r = getFreeMemory();
                k = (int)r/100000;
                //setMas(k)
                AL.add(k);

                tv.setText("Free memory : " +  k);
                t++;
                if(t == 5){
                    cancel();
                    b2.setClickable(true);

                }






            }
        });
    }

    public void setMas(long p){

        //if(ii==5){}

        //Log.d("LOG_TAG", "SetMy_Array[0]: " + k + "SetMy_Array[1]: " + k);
        ii++;
    }






    /*public long getMas(){
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "GetMy_Array[0]: " + k + "GetMy_Array[1]: " + k);
        return k;

    }*/
}
```

}

**Second class**

```
package foxstrot.p3;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 14.04.2015.
 */

    public class G extends Activity {

    int ii;




    private long[] My_Array ;
    private MainActivity  mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    //private MainActivity.MyTimerTask myTimerTask = mainActivity.new MyTimerTask();
    //private long[] G_mas =  myTimerTask.getMas();
    ArrayList<Integer> AL  = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
    Intent intent;


    private boolean drawGraph = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawView(this));
        intent = getIntent();

        //AL = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("Joker");

        //Log.d("LOG_TAG","Al: " + AL.get(0) + "AL: " + AL.get(0));


        //My_Array = myTimerTask.getMas();
        //Log.d("LOG_TAG","My_Array[0]: " + myTimerTask.getMas() + "My_Array[1]: " + myTimerTask.getMas());

        /*for(int i=0;i<G_mas.length;i++){
            max = Math.max(max,G_mas[i]);
            min = G_mas[i];
            min = Math.min(min, G_mas[i]);
        }*/





    }


      public  class DrawView extends View{
          Paint p;
          Rect rect;
          int uN = 0;
          int uT = 0;
          int y1 = 0;
          int x1 = 0;
          int n = 2000;
          int t = 0;





             public DrawView(Context context){
                super(context);
                 p = new Paint();
                rect = new Rect();
             }

            @Override
            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                final int cHeight = canvas.getHeight();
                final int cWidth = canvas.getWidth();


                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setTextSize(30);
                canvas.drawLine(80,0,80,cHeight-60,paint);
                canvas.drawLine(80,cHeight-60,cWidth,cHeight-60,paint);
                for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
                    canvas.drawText(uT + "" , 10 , 25 + y1, paint);

                    uT = uT + 3;
                    y1 = y1 + (cHeight/50);
                }

                for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
                    canvas.drawText("|"+ uN, 75 + x1, cHeight - 25 , paint);
                    uN = uN + 1000;
                    x1 = x1 + (cWidth/9)-25;

                    /*int joker = 10;
                    canvas.drawPoint(20+ joker,20,paint);
                    joker = joker + 40;*/
                }
                paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
                /*for(int i=0;i<My_Array.length;i++){

                    long xc = (My_Array[i] * (cWidth-80)) / 8000 ;
                    int yc = (t * (cHeight-60))/147;
                    t = t + 3;
                    canvas.drawPoint(xc, yc, paint);
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG","xc: " + xc + "yc: " + yc);

                }*/



                /*Paint paint2 = new Paint();
                paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawPoint(cWidth, cHeight, paint2);*/







            }


        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `putExtra()` and `getLongArrayExtra()`.

Documentation: [putExtra(String name, long[] value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20long[])) and [getLongArrayExtra(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getLongArrayExtra(java.lang.String))

In MainActivity.java:

```
public void chart(View v){
    i = new Intent(this,G.class);
    i.putExtra("foxstrot.p3.masiv", Masiv);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In G.java:

```
private boolean drawGraph = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawView(this));
        intent = getIntent();

        My_Array = intent.getLongArrayExtra("foxstrot.p3.masiv");
        //...................
```